# Disable Url Encoding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, urldecode

In my ASP.NET MVC application, there is url for example:

```
<img src="/photo/22316/byt+3%2b1+n.s+(16)/600x400">
```

which is mapped to action

```
public void Photo(string sid, string name, int? width, int? height)
{     
  //read image, resize and return
}
```

The problem is that the string

```
byt+3%2b1+n.s+(16)
```

is automatically decoded by ASP.NET MVC as

```
byt+3+1+n.s+(9)
```

and the image cannot be found, because the name of file is

```
byt 3+1+n.s (9).jpg
```

I cannot even replace + for space, because only some of plus marks were created by encoding. I need to disable the encoding of parameter of this particular action to solve this issue.

I know that it is better to generate some IDs, but it is late know to change id, I need to preserve the url of images because of compatibility issues and google image search.

The Url routing is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
null,
"photo/{sid}/{name}/{width}x{height}", // URL
new { controller = "Nemovitost", action = "Foto" }
);
```

In watch there is:

```
HttpContext.Request.Url = {http://localhost:31182/photo/22316/byt+3+1+n.s+(9)/600x400}
```

But in fiddler I can see:

```
http://localhost:31182/photo/22316/byt+3%2b1+n.s+(9)/600x400
```

The razor template (simplified):

```
public static string BuildImageUrl(int realtyId, string filename, int w, int h)
{
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

    return string.Format("/photo/{0}/{1}/{2}x{3}", realtyId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename), w, h).ToLower();
}

var rsImgF = "<img src=\"{0}\">";

....                       

var rsImg = string.Format(rsImgF, ....,
    BuildImageUrl(Model.RealtyId, img.Filename, 600, 400));

@Html.Raw(rsImg);
```

Comment: that's not url encoding. If you url encode the actual file name, you'd see `%20` where spaces are.  I think you're doing something to cause that.

Comment: what's your url route definition look like?

Comment: please see url route in edit

Comment: And we also need to see the razor code for this view, and any templates you may use.

Comment: please see the simplified template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine to remove the url encoding and just use the built in Razor Url encoding, which is applied automatically when using `@`:

```
public static string BuildImageUrl(int realtyId, string filename, int w, int h)
{
    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);

    // no url encoding here!
    return string.Format("/photo/{0}/{1}/{2}x{3}", realtyId, filename, w, h).ToLower();
}

var rsImgF = "<img src=\"{0}\">";

....                       

var rsImg = string.Format(rsImgF, ....,
    BuildImageUrl(Model.RealtyId, img.Filename, 600, 400));

@rsImg;
```

Comment: I cannot use @rsImg because of HTML tags in rsImg string, but it works even with @Html.Raw(rsImg). Thanks